# What would be the size of a hydrogen atom with its electron if it's scaled up?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, dimensional-analysis, estimation

I began wondering that if I wanted to make a precise scale model of a hydrogen atom, with the electron being $1$ cm in size, how big should the nucleus be and how far away should the electron be from the nucleus?

I tried asking this from [GPT-4](https://openai.com/product/gpt-4) (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-4)) and [Claude.ai](https://claude.ai/login) multiple times, but every time I get a different answer and the answers vary wildly.

Comment: Just get some ideas from the AI but make your own judgement. Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 7):

There's a problem with your plan. To scale an electron up to 1 cm, you'd need to know it's a specific nonzero size first. As far as we know, the electron is a point particle. It might not be, but all we have is [an upper bound on its radius](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-8949/1988/T22/016): $10^{-20}\mbox{cm}$. If on the other hand you scaled the hydrogen atom so the proton is a certain size, you'd only have to contend with [a debate of a few percent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_radius_puzzle), but then you wouldn't know how big your electron ends up because, again, it might be a point.

Comment: Fair. If we took this upper bound as the radius for our model electron and scaled that up to 1 cm, what would be the size of the nucleus with the same scale factor and how far would the electron in our model be from the nucleus?

Comment: @Henno If we made every length scale $10^{20}$ times bigger, the proton radius would be about 50 miles (the diameter is twice that), while the Bohr radius - not that the electron is really a certain distance from the nucleus, but let's neglect quantum mechanics for the moment - would be about 15 times the distance from Earth to the Moon.

Answer (score 4):

The standard answer is if you scaled up the proton to the size of ~something like a pea, the average radius of the electron's position "cloud" would be roughly the length of a football field.

Answer (score 2):

So you'd have to use the Compton wavelength of the electron $\lambda_e = \frac 1 2 $ cm, and the Bohr radius is:

$$a_0 = \frac{\alpha \lambda_e}{2\pi} \approx 11{\,}{\rm cm}$$

You could estimate the proton size as:

$$r_p --> a_0 \frac{m_e}{m_p} $$

which is off by a factor of 30...$\alpha_s$ matters. A proton radius is 0.88 fm, so we're at 200 micron in the model.

If you redo starting with the classical electron radius, everything is expands by a factor of 137 ($1/\alpha$).